# Prove: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 2$ indicate $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$

Tags: calculus

This question is from last year exam in calculus.
In the answers they mentioned more than one way to solve this question.
The method they used is to build a new function but it was a bit complicated.
I would like to get some help.

Comment: To clarify, are you asking to prove $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 2 \implies \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$?

Comment: This should be obvious intuitively: eventually $f$ is increasing at a rate of around $2$ vertical units per horizontal unit.  So it's going to get bigger forever.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! By the way, I think that the only value of $a$ for which $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=a$ does *not* imply $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$ is $a=0$.

Comment: Hint: Use Mean Value Theorem on each intervals $[n,n+1]$ for $n \in \Bbb N$ and then do a telescoping sum

Answer (score 4):

By definition of limit, let $M$ such that $x \geq M \implies f'(x) > 2-\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{2}$. Then we have, for $x > M$
$$f(x) - f(M) = \int_x^M f'(t) dt \geq \frac{3}{2} (x-M),$$
that is
$$ f(x) \geq f(M) + \frac{3}{2} (x-M).$$

Now for any number $L$ we can find $N$ big enough so that
$f(M) + \frac{3}{2} (x-M) > L$
when $x > N$, and this proves that $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to show that $f$ is bounded below by a function which goes to infinity as $x \to \infty$.  It follows from your hypothesis that there exists an $x_0$ such that for all $x \geq x_0$, $f'(x) \geq 1$.

Now let $x$ be any number bigger than $x_0$.  Consider the average rate of change

$$\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

between $x$ and $x_0$.  By the mean value theorem, there exists a $c > x_0$ such that

$$\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(c)$$

Since $f'(c) \geq 1$, this implies that there is a constant $K$ such that $f(x) \geq x +K$ for all $x > x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

By L'Hôpital's rule
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f'(x)}}{1} = 2.
$$
Thus
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } f(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } x\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{f(x)}}{x} =  + \infty .
$$

Comment: How can you apply l'Hospital without knowing à priori that you are in a $\frac \infty\infty$ form ? This is circular proof.

Comment: @ zwim LH applies to limits of the form ${{\rm anything}\over\infty}$.